# Backbone Boilerplate problems with command release and Handlebars

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, backbone-boilerplate

I cant seem to get this to work. I am using [BBB-Handlebars](https://github.com/tbranyen/boilerplate-handlebars-layoutmanager). When I use this during development, the application renders perfectly and I have no issues. As soon as I run the command BBB release and point my application to the built and compiled require.js file, my templates don't render. For example, my templates will render with `{{model.someAttribute}}` instead of `{{The models attribute}}`. So its keeping the brackets intact and for some reason Handlebars is treating the entire template as Html. Its not rendering out the data. I have tried different combinations by editing the grunt.js file, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I gave up on the backbone boiler plate build tools and am now looking at http://yeoman.io/ which seems more dependable AND will allow you to initialise a backbone boilerplate project. Surely you shouldn't be required to change your app class after you've built?

Comment: Thanks @net.uk.sweet. I have actually tried Yeoman, and I honestly found it a little too opinionated for me. Decided to stick with CodeKit and BBB for the time being. Actually found the issue which I will post below.

Comment: Good job. Glad you tracked it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone else having this issue, I changed the following:

```
grunt.registerTask("debug", "clean lint jst requirejs concat stylus:compile");
```

To:

```
grunt.registerTask("debug", "clean lint jst handlebars requirejs concat");
```

I don't need stylus, so I removed it. Just added Handlebars task and seemed to sort out the issue. Let me know if you are still having problems.